# Populating a grid with multiple variables

Tags: python, grid, python-3.4

I have been coding for about 1 and half years now on and off, but I still don't get how grids work in Python.

So my problem is that I have to make a grid to display a population model. So I need to populate my grid with different variables that change for every row you have in the grid:
[image]

So how would I got about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really don't need a concept of a grid to accomplish what you want.  You simply need a `generator` to propagate your population from one generation to the next.  You can then use Python's [Format Specification Mini-Language](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatspec) to print the values in a table that matches your example output.

```
def propagate(num_generations, population_start = None):
    if population_start is None:
        population = [10, 10, 10, 30]
    else:
        population = population_start
    for gen in range(num_generations):
        yield population
        population = [population[1]*2, population[0], population[1]]
        population.append(sum(population))

def print_propagation(num_generations, population_start = None):
    print('GENERATION\tJUVENILES\tADULTS\tSENILES\t\tTOTAL')
    for gen, pops in enumerate(propagate(num_generations, population_start)):
        print('{:^10}\t{:^8}\t{:^6}\t{:^7}\t\t{:^5}'.format(gen, *pops))
```

You can use the above functions like so:

```
>>> list(propagate(6))
[[10, 10, 10, 30],
 [20, 10, 10, 40],
 [20, 20, 10, 50],
 [40, 20, 20, 80],
 [40, 40, 20, 100],
 [80, 40, 40, 160]]

>>> print_propagation(6)
GENERATION      JUVENILES       ADULTS  SENILES         TOTAL
    0              10             10      10             30  
    1              20             10      10             40  
    2              20             20      10             50  
    3              40             20      20             80  
    4              40             40      20             100 
    5              80             40      40             160
```

Comment: Thank you very much!! Just so I can better understand what is going on please could you explain what -  '{:^10}\t{:^8}\t{:^6}\t{:^7}\t\t{:^5} - does?

Comment: See the Python Format Specification Mini Language documentation (link above).  Each set of braces (the `{}`s) will include the unpacked arguments from the `.format` method call, and the `^10` strings indicate that each value will be center aligned within that field in the string.